# Getting the Un-selected values from the listbox

Tags: jquery, select, jquery-selectors

I am using jquery [Ui Multiselect](http://quasipartikel.at/multiselect_original/) plugin ,

[image: UI Multiselect]

I would use `$('#select').val();` to get the selected values from (values at right box) . But how to get the un-selceted values from the select . (it is a single select box)

Is there any way to get the values from the left box (Un-selected values). i am populating its values using `<option>1<option>` and the selected values as `<option selected>1</option>`

Thanks for your help in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```js
$('button').click(function() {

  var vals = $('select option').not(':selected').map(function() {
    return this.value;
  }).get();

  $('#result').html(vals.join())
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
</select>
<button>Test</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. sorry this may seem noob question , but didnt find it anywhere